# HTML file created by folium is blank

Tags: html, mapping, folium

Everything in python shell tells me no errors, as it's the example of a tutorial, but still gives me a blank page however and every time I try to open it.

```
import folium
map = folium.Map(location=[38.58,-99.09])
map.save('map1.html')
```

It's supposed to preview a street view as simple as that, and the tutor simply doesn't show the reason or whether one should encounter any error.
here's the created file of .html

*I tried attaching the HTML file script, but the website flagged it as spam*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcHIe.png)
so here's some errors appear when I inspect the page.
I'm really a beginner at coding, so please help me.